# FactoryGirl not creating unique objects

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec2, factory-bot, faker

I have a failing test where, to my understanding, it should be creating objects with unique values by using the Faker gem. I'm really stuck here. Thanks for the help!

Failing test from user_spec.rb:

```
describe "post associations" do
   before { @user.save }
   let!(:older_post) do
     older_post = FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: @user, created_at: 1.day.ago)
     older_post.add_tags!([Faker::Lorem.words(1), Faker::Lorem.words(1), Faker::Lorem.words(1)])
  end
  let!(:newer_post) do
     newer_post = FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: @user, created_at: 1.hour.ago)
     newer_post.add_tags!([Faker::Lorem.words(1), Faker::Lorem.words(1), Faker::Lorem.words(1)])
   end

   it "should have the right posts in the right order" do
     @user.posts.should == [newer_post, older_post]
   end 
end
```

Post factory:

```
    factory :post do
    title       Faker::Lorem.sentence(Random.rand(1..5))
    content     Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(3)
    shared_url  Faker::Internet.url
    public_post true
    user
end
```

Rspec results:

```
1) User post associations should have the right posts in the right order
 Failure/Error: @user.posts.should == [newer_post, older_post]
   expected: [true, true]
        got: [#<Post id: 2, title: "Sapiente dignissimos qui et a.", content: "---\n- Quis necessitatibus eligendi sunt distinctio ...", shared_url: "http://blanda.biz/xander.cormier", public_post: true, created_at: "2013-06-28 15:31:00", updated_at: "2013-06-28 16:31:00", user_id: 1>, #<Post id: 1, title: "Sapiente dignissimos qui et a.", content: "---\n- Quis necessitatibus eligendi sunt distinctio ...", shared_url: "http://blanda.biz/xander.cormier", public_post: true, created_at: "2013-06-27 16:31:00", updated_at: "2013-06-28 16:31:00", user_id: 1>] (using ==)
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
   -[true, true]
   +[#<Post id: 2, title: "Sapiente dignissimos qui et a.", content: "---\n- Quis necessitatibus eligendi sunt distinctio ...", shared_url: "http://blanda.biz/xander.cormier", public_post: true, created_at: "2013-06-28 15:31:00", updated_at: "2013-06-28 16:31:00", user_id: 1>,
   + #<Post id: 1, title: "Sapiente dignissimos qui et a.", content: "---\n- Quis necessitatibus eligendi sunt distinctio ...", shared_url: "http://blanda.biz/xander.cormier", public_post: true, created_at: "2013-06-27 16:31:00", updated_at: "2013-06-28 16:31:00", user_id: 1>]

 # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:94:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of your `:let!` blocks, the last line evaluated is the `add_tags!` method, which appears to be returning `true` instead of the post the tags were added to. Because of this, in your spec `[newer_post, older_post]` actually equals `[true, true]` instead of your actual posts.

At the end of each `:let!` block, return the post:

```
let!(:older_post) do
  older_post = FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: @user, created_at: 1.day.ago)
  older_post.add_tags!([Faker::Lorem.words(1), Faker::Lorem.words(1), Faker::Lorem.words(1)])
  older_post
end

let!(:newer_post) do
  newer_post = FactoryGirl.create(:post, user: @user, created_at: 1.hour.ago)
  newer_post.add_tags!([Faker::Lorem.words(1), Faker::Lorem.words(1), Faker::Lorem.words(1)])
  newer_post
end
```

Alternatively, you could change your `add_tags!` method to return the post instead of `true`/`false`.